# How to define bound type parameters in Java inner class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes, bounded-types

```
public class TowerOfHanoi<E> {
    private class Disk<T extends Comparable<E>> {
    }

    private class Peg<S extends Disk<T extends Comparable<E>>> extends Stack<Disk<T extends Comparable<E>>> {
    }
}
```

With the above code, I'm getting the following compilation error.

> Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

However, if I change the definition of Peg as follows, it works:

```
private class Peg<T extends Disk<? extends Comparable<E>>> extends Stack<Disk<? extends Comparable<E>>> {
}
```

I don't want to use a wildcard. Is there a way to change that to a named parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use generics like that. Simply pass the type (not the bound) to the extended type.

This compiles:

```
public class TowerOfHanoi<E> {
    private class Disk<T extends Comparable<E>> {
    }

    private class Peg<T extends Disk<Comparable<E>>> extends Stack<Disk<Comparable<E>>> {
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that Disk<Comparable<E> is only gonna accept Comparable<E> and not any subclasses of it. See my edit.

Comment: No. It will accept any class that extends `Comparable<E>`. The `Disk` implementation must be defined as `Disk<Comparable<E>>`, but you can use any subclass of `Comparable<E>` with it

Comment: I ended up making Disk a non-generic type. In the end, this was taking up more time that the actual algorithm, so it seemed like I made it unnecessarily complex. I will accept your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you can't make `E` comparable?

```
public class TowerOfHanoi<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
{
    private class Disk implements Comparable<Disk> { }

    private class Peg extends Stack<Disk> { }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that but it didn't seem like the right thing to do. Disks need to be compared with one another, so I felt that only the Disk class should impose a restriction on the type but not the outer class TowerOfHanoi. If you find an argument against that, let me know.

Comment: If `TowerOfHanoi<E>` will create instances of `Disk<E>`, then `E` needs to be comparable.

Comment: That's not correct; with @Bohemian's solution above, it would work without making E comparable. I ended up cleaning it up anyway as I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, what I said *is* correct. Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/twmHa6).

Comment: That's because you are declaring Disk<E>; if you replace Disk<E> with Disk<Comparable<E>>, it'd compile fine.